# How can I move the mail from Inbox to another folder in GraphAPI

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api

How do I move an email from the Inbox to the Junk E-mail folder in the outlook?

I tried using below code:

```
private static void moveMailsToOtherFolder(String o365Mailbox, Message message) {
    System.out.println(message.id);
            
         _appClient.users(o365Mailbox)
                 .mailFolders(message.id)
                .move(MailFolderMoveParameterSet
                .newBuilder()
                .withDestinationId("Junk E-mail")
                .build())
            .buildRequest()
            .post();
            
}
```

But get the error:

```
SEVERE: Throwable detail: com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphServiceException: Error code: ErrorInvalidIdMalformed
Error message: Id is malformed.
```

Can any help me on this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the MS Graph API, but from the error message and looking that the JavaDocs (https://javadoc.io/static/com.microsoft.graph/microsoft-graph/5.77.0/com/microsoft/graph/models/Message.html#parentFolderId), I suspect `message.id` should be `message.parentFolderId`.

Comment: @NickHolt tried with message.parentFolderId getting null value.

Comment: Even I try to pass message.parentFolderId . but I am getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move message the call `messages` instead of `mailFolders`

```
private static void moveMailsToOtherFolder(String o365Mailbox, Message message) {
    System.out.println(message.id);
            
         _appClient.users(o365Mailbox)
                 .messages(message.id)
                .move(MessageMoveParameterSet
                .newBuilder()
                .withDestinationId("Junk E-mail")
                .build())
            .buildRequest()
            .post();
            
}
```

Comment: I tried with above code. but it giving compile time error like below.                               The method move(MessageMoveParameterSet) in the type MessageRequestBuilder is not applicable for the arguments (MailFolderMoveParameterSet)

Comment: @ManiBellamkonda Thank, it should be MessageMoveParameterSet not MailFolderMoveParameterSet, updated the answer

Comment: I tried with MessageMoveParameterSet , even I am getting same error.